# Is there a way to optimize this query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization, mysql-workbench

I have written a query but it's taking a lot of time. I want to know if there exists any solution to optimize it without making a temp table in MYSQL. Is there a way to optimize the subquery part since AccessLog2019  is huge so it's taking forever)

Here is my query

```
SELECT distinct l.ListingID,l.City,l.ListingStatus,l.Price,l.Bedrooms,l.FullBathrooms, gc.Latitude,gc.Longitude , count(distinct s.AccessLogID) AS access_count, s.LBID , lb.CurrentListingID
from lockbox.Listings l 
JOIN lockbox.GeoCoordinates gc ON l.ListingID = gc.ID
LEFT JOIN lockbox.LockBox lb ON l.ListingID = lb.CurrentListingID
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT  * FROM  lockbox.AccessLog2019 ac where ac.AccessType not in('1DayCodeGen','BluCodeGen','SmartMACGen') AND  DATEDIFF(NOW(), ac.UTCAccessedDT ) < 1 ) s
ON lb.LBID = s.LBID
WHERE  l.AssocID = 'AS00000000CC' AND  (gc.Confidence  <> '5 - Unmatchable' OR  gc.Confidence  IS NULL OR gc.Confidence = ' ') 
group BY l.ListingID
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you need `*` from `AccessLog2019`? Also have you indexed the tables?

Comment: FYI, many Stack Overflow answerers don't even look at query-optimization questions unless you share the output of (a) `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>\G` for each table in the query, (b) `EXPLAIN` for the query, and (c) `SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE '<tablename>'\G` for each table in the query.

Comment: to add to @BillKarwin 's comment, then we can also verify if GROUP BY is used correctly here, this seams to be non standard (SQL 1992) GROUP BY usage, and is only valid when runing on SQL 1999+ standards which MySQL 5.7.5+ supports (with enabled ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode) which is called [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).. ..

Comment: As written, your date calculation cannot use a function, but it is possible to rearrange that part

Comment: To elaborate on @PritamBanerjee's comment, you might want to try adding an index on AccessType for table lockbox.AccessLog2019 to help the "where not in ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try breaking out the subquery to the JOIN clause.

It might give a hint to the optimizer that it can use the LBID field first, and then test the AccessType later (in case the optimizer doesn't figure that out when you have the sub-select).

```
SELECT distinct l.ListingID,l.City,l.ListingStatus,l.Price,l.Bedrooms,l.FullBathrooms, gc.Latitude,gc.Longitude , count(distinct s.AccessLogID) AS access_count, s.LBID , lb.CurrentListingID
from lockbox.Listings l 
JOIN lockbox.GeoCoordinates gc ON l.ListingID = gc.ID
LEFT JOIN lockbox.LockBox lb ON l.ListingID = lb.CurrentListingID
LEFT JOIN AccessLog2019 s
ON lb.LBID = s.LBID
   AND s.AccessType not in('1DayCodeGen','BluCodeGen','SmartMACGen')
   AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), s.UTCAccessedDT ) < 1
WHERE  l.AssocID = 'AS00000000CC' AND  (gc.Confidence  <> '5 - Unmatchable' OR  gc.Confidence  IS NULL OR gc.Confidence = ' ') 
group BY l.ListingID
```

Note that this is one of those cases where conditions in the JOIN clause gives different behavior than using a WHERE clause.  If you just had `lb.LBID = s.LBID` and then had the conditions I wrote in the `WHERE` of the outer query the results would be different.  They would exclude the records matching `lb.LBID = s.LBID`.  But in the `JOIN` clause, it is part of the conditions of the outer join.

Comment: This seams to be non standard (SQL 1992) GROUP BY usage, and is only valid when running on SQL 1999+ standards which MySQL 5.7.5+ supports (with enabled ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY sql_mode)  which is called [functional dependency](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) ... With other words the results which this query can give might be invalid as in unrelated values per group...

Comment: @RaymondNijland Yes, I have noticed that mysql supports a non-standard SQL feature of doing a group by with a primary key, without listing all the fields.

Comment: *"Yes, I have noticed that mysql supports a non-standard SQL feature of doing a group by with a primary key"* Uhm functional dependency is in fact defined as **optional feature** in ANSI/ISO SQL 99 ... Not sure anymore if the ANSI/ISO SQL standard does further then MySQL supports to find functional dependencies on runtime (meaning queries running with  `DISTINCT` as easy example) and not out of **unique** table constraints only..

Answer (score 2):

If you can avoid the outer `group by`, that is a big win.  I am thinking:

```
SELECT l.ListingID, l.City, l.ListingStatus, l.Price, l.Bedrooms, l.FullBathrooms,
       gc.Latitude, gc.Longitude,
       (select count(*)
        from lockbox.LockBox lb join
             lockbox.AccessLog2019 ac
             on lb.LBID = ac.LBID       
        where l.ListingID = lb.CurrentListingID and
              ac.AccessType not in ('1DayCodeGen', 'BluCodeGen', 'SmartMACGen') and
              DATEDIFF(NOW(), ac.UTCAccessedDT) < 1
       ) as cnt
from lockbox.Listings l JOIN
     lockbox.GeoCoordinates gc
     ON l.ListingID = gc.ID
WHERE l.AssocID = 'AS00000000CC' AND
      (gc.Confidence  <> '5 - Unmatchable' OR 
       gc.Confidence  IS NULL OR
       gc.Confidence = ' '
      )
```

Note:  This does not select `s.LBID` or `lb.CurrentListingID` because these don't make sense in your query.  If I understand correctly, these could have different values on different rows.

Answer (score 1):

- `SELECT  *` --> Select only the columns needed.
- `SELECT DISTINCT ... GROUP BY` -- Do one or the other, not both.
- Need composite `INDEX(AssocID, ListingID)` (in that order)
- `DATEDIFF(NOW(), ac.UTCAccessedDT ) < 1` --> `ac.UTCAccessedDT > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY` (or whatever your intent was.  Then add `INDEX(UTCAccessedDT)`
- `OR` is hard to optimize; consider cleansing the data so that `Confidence` does not have 3 values that mean the same thing.